# Selecting ImageButton and TextView simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know if there is a way to select(highlight on clicking) an ImageButton and TextView simultaneously. I have an ImageButton and TextView. I have put them in a RelativeLayout and set the background to a drawable selector xml. But they are not highlighting together. If I press the ImageButton button it highlights alone and if I press the layout it highlights without highlighting the ImageButton. Could you please help me in this aspect?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your action listener code

Comment: Make sure your `RelativeLayout` is clickable and assign your onClickListener to your layout rather than on the Text- or ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the solution for you

- wrap the `ImageButton` and 'TextView' in a 'LinearLayout'
- Disable the `clickable`, `focusable` events of Imagebutton and textview
- Apply a custom selector for your `LinearLayout`

here goes the updated `custom_component.xml` layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCustomComponent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bgimage_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/testImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Test Text"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this layout file uses custom selector xml file `layout_bgimage_selector.xml`, which needs to be placed in `res/drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_over" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_over" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" android:state_enabled="true"/>

</selector>
```

the 9-patch images i used for layout selector are :

background.9.png - [image: background.9.png]

background_over.9.png - [image: background_over.9.png]

place them in `res/drawable-hdpi` folder. (or any image resource folder that matches your device configs)

Answer (score 1):

use a custom background for the parent layout of the TextView and ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background_focused"        />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background_focused"        />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background_focused"        />
    <item
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_background_unfocused"      />
</selector>
```

and write the respective code in the onclickListener of the parent layout instead of child views.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to declare a single button that includes text and image like this.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/dash_bt_list"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_image"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:onClick="onClickFeature"
        android:text="@string/your_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

And in your selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
               <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
               <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"
                   android:top="1dp" />
            </shape>
            ...
    </selector>
```

That helped me